# JSON response in CakePHP 3.5

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am new to CakePHP framework. I have been stuck on an issue for sometime now.

I am trying to make a json response work. I have read the tutorial on how to here:[JSON and XML views in CakePHP](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html). However, it is still not working on my end.

**Here is my code:**

Inside my controller - `App\Controller\ExpensesController`

```
public function getMonthlyExpenses($month = null) {

    $expenses = $this->Expenses->find('all'); 

    $this->set(compact($expenses, $month)); 

    $this->set('_serialize', array("expenses", "month"));   

}
```

I am calling `getMonthlyExpenses` inside a View Element - `/src/Template/Element/Chart/expenseChart.ctp`

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: '/finance/expenses/getMonthlyExpenses/3.json',
        accepts: 'application/json', 
        async: false, 
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("data" + data);
        }, 
     error: function() {
        console.log("there was an error");
    }
});
</script>
```

In my Configuration - `Routes.php' I have

```
<?php

use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder;
use Cake\Routing\Router;
use Cake\Routing\Route\DashedRoute;


Router::defaultRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);

Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {

    $routes->extensions(['json']);
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);


    $routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);


    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);

});


Plugin::routes();
```

**Results**

1. When I access the Action controller directly via `/expenses/getMonthlyExpenses/3.json`. I simply get a `null` response with `json/application` contentType.
2. When I access the template where the View element is called - `/finance/expenses/index`, it returns `null` as well.

Thank you , 
ANy help would be appreciated. I am sure there is something really simple that I am overlooking.

Comment: Please post your full routes.php file, but I will attempt to answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change:

```
$this->set(compact($expenses, $month));
```

to

```
$this->set(compact("expenses", "month"));
```

It looks like the [compact function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) accepts either variable names or array of name => variable.

Comment: Yes, this fixed it. Thank you. Its weird how you reference variables and define variables in such a mannar.

Comment: Yep, confusing a bit, agree

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar application running CakePHP 3.5, here is a sample of my routes file, perhaps you missed something. Mine is slightly different since my REST api sits in a plugin.

```
Router::plugin('Api', ['path' => '/publisher/], function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
        $routes->extensions(['json']);
        $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
    }
);
```

Try changing your AJAX request endpoint from getMonthlyExpenses to either get-monthly-expenses or get_monthly_expenses, I believe thats where your problem may be.

Also try debugging a bit more by simply doing a die('hello world') at the beginning of your controller functions.

Additionally try a different way of setting the results:

```
public function getMonthlyExpenses($month = null) {

    $expenses = $this->Expenses->find('all'); 

    $this->set(compact($expenses, $month)); 

    $this->set('_serialize', true);   

}
```

Comment: I've added my entire routes.php file

Comment: Did you try the other debugging steps I mentioned?

Comment: I changed the ajax url to `get-monthly-expenses` and `get_monthly_expenses` but I am still getting null. However `die("hello world")` is returns 'hello world' in the response.

Comment: Updated answer with something new to try